# HTTP 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: r, web-services, curl, rcurl

I am trying to post a XML file (test1.xml) and receive an output from a webservice API. I get an error **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**. This is the code below.

```
 myheader=c(Connection="close", 
       'Content-Type' = "application/xml",
       'Content-length' =nchar("test1.xml"))

 data =  getURL("http://abcd/efg/requests/",
           userpwd="m12345:123456", httpauth = 1L,
           postfields="test1.xml",
           httpheader=myheader,
           verbose=TRUE)
```

This is the output

```
 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
 *   Trying 123.456.789.123...
 * Connected to rcftomdev1 (123.456.789.123) port 8086 (#0)
 * Server auth using Basic with user 'm12345'
 > POST /dart/requests/ HTTP/1.1
 Authorization: Basic bTEzNDQ4M#$#$#$#$%5==
 Host: abcd:8086
 Accept: */*
 Connection: close
 Content-Type: application/xml
 Content-length: 9

 * upload completely sent off: 9 out of 9 bytes
 < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
 < Content-Length: 968
 < Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 07:50:05 GMT
 < Connection: close
 < 
 * Closing connection 0
```

Not sure where I am going wrong, need help ?

Answer (score 0):

If that was indeed exactly what was sent in the Authorization: header for the given user+password then something seriously wrong happened as your combo should've created `bTEyMzQ1OjEyMzQ1Ngo=`.

The other aspects of the request looks fine so only reading up on the server side requirements for this server and API will give you the answer.